# Calling ASP.NET MVC 4 Controller from Javascript

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm calling an ASP.NET MVC 4 control method from Javascript (in a cshtml file) using $.ajax() as shown below

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { 'id': "123"},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

The controller action method is

```
    public JsonResult MyAction(string id)
    {
        // Do stuff
        return new JsonResult();
    }
```

which is getting called ok but is causing a GET 500 (Internal Server Error).

I don't really care about the returned data I just want to call the controller method to update a model.

Can anyone let me know why I'm getting the 500 or an alternative way of doing this that would be great.

Comment: Looks like problem is in `// Do stuff` code..

Comment: Must be `return new JsonResult(/*stuff*/,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowedGet);`?

Comment: That's just a place holder the controller is not actually doing anything at the moment. The method is as shown.

Comment: Returning Json("Stuff", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons you cannot use the GET method in ajax requests (See [JSON Hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx)).

You just have to do it like this:

```
   return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

or better off, change the method to post

```
   type: 'POST',
```